# Is there a format like polyline6 but with altitude for API

Tags: rest, format, coordinates, polyline

I develop a REST API and need to send/receive coordinates with their altitude.

For now we only needed latitude and longitude so we were using Polyline6 to have an efficient way to transfer data. Polyline6 is very efficient because it does two things : computes differential data, not the whole data, and then encode it.

Now, we need to add altitude data to the coordinates but Polyline6 does not support it. Transferring a large number of coordinates can take a long time and I would like to be as efficient as possible. I would like to avoid to transfer an array of [longitude, latitude, altitude] or to manually compress data with gzip and base64.

Do you know an alternative to Polyline6 which supports altitude, or any standard format which could fit to my need ?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm